# Convert Ruby array into R array or vectors

Tags: ruby, arrays, r, quantmod

I got problem while I am converting a Ruby array into a vector in R.

```
def self.risk_return_plot(stock_ticker = ["VZ", "CHU", "T", "VOD", "DTEGY"])
   RSERVE.eval <<EOF
   myenv <- new.env()
   getSymbols("#{@stock_ticker}", env = myenv)
   monthly.Return <- do.call(merge, c(eapply(myenv, monthlyReturn), all=FALSE))
   names(monthly.Return)[1:ncol(monthly.Return)] <- paste("#{@stock_ticker}", 1:ncol(monthly.Return), sep="")
   EOF
end
```

When I send the command to the R server, it shows an error saying that Eval error: `getSymbols(["VZ", "CHU", "T", "VOD", "DTEGY"])`, and the correct type would be `getSymbols(c("VZ", "CHU", "T", "VOD", "DTEGY"))` in R.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have defined an array in Ruby? And trying to read that using R? Is so, what is the intermediary step - are you writing the array to a file to be read by R? Puzzled.

Comment: Are you using [RinRuby](https://sites.google.com/a/ddahl.org/rinruby-users/)?

Comment: yes.I use Rinruby and R.eval <<EOF

Comment: @SlowLearner I just update the code and the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, you want to create R a snippet of code, on the fly, and execute it on a R server.

You need to some fixes on your code:

```
def self.risk_return_plot(stock_ticker = ["VZ", "CHU", "T", "VOD", "DTEGY"])
   # creates a R vector version from stock_ticker array
   # enclose each item with " char, join with ',' and enclose all with c()
   r_vector = "c(#{stock_ticker.map() {|item| "\"#{item}\""}.join(',')})"
   # send R command string to the server
   RSERVE.eval <<-EOF
   myenv <- new.env()
   getSymbols(#{r_vector}, env = myenv)
   monthly.Return <- do.call(merge, c(eapply(myenv, monthlyReturn), all=FALSE))
   names(monthly.Return)[1:ncol(monthly.Return)] <- paste(#{r_vector}, 1:ncol(monthly.Return), sep="")
   EOF
end
```

Comment: I run this, it still shows an error: RinRuby::ParseError: Parse error on eval: getSymbols("c("VZ","CHU","T","VOD","DTEGY")", env = myenv), we need to remove the ""outside the c("VZ","CHU","T","VOD","DTEGY").

Comment: I forgot to remove. It's ok now.